# How to save shared excel file using openpyxl?

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I am trying to save a shared excel file that I have edited with python 3.7 and openpyxl. When I save it, it removes the shared property of the excel. Got stuck at this. I just save it with `workbook.save('filepath')` command. I was not able to find anything related in the documentation.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can currently do that with openpyxl as the functionality doesn't appear to be implemented in the ExcelWriter class.

Given that Microsoft is trying to deprecate shared workbooks in favor of [co-authoring](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/about-the-shared-workbook-feature-49b833c0-873b-48d8-8bf2-c1c59a628534)

> Important: "Shared Workbooks" is an older feature that allows you to
> collaborate on a workbook with multiple people. This feature has many
> limitations, and has been replaced by co-authoring. Co-authoring is
> available in certain versions of Excel, including Excel 2016 for
> Office 365 subscribers.

I doubt that this ranks highly on the roadmap.

You could XML hack it together by setting the shared docflag in the raw xml `app.xml` under the `docProps` inside an xlsx file or by overriding the document module [extended properties here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.packaging.extended.html?highlight=shareddoc#openpyxl.packaging.extended.ExtendedProperties.SharedDoc).

Comment: I tried to modify the extended properties, but the result was the same. When I modify xml files, the workbook gets corrupted. Help would be greatly appreciated.